# ActiveDirectoryMembersipProvider availability on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm attempting to get AD authentication working on an Azure Website (WAWS) (please note, not a cloud service or VM).

The site (a basic MVC3 site, with no changes except the membership provider and relevant Connection String) will load correctly, however, when I attempt to login I get a configuration exception:

```
Parser Error Message: Access is denied.

Line 51:         <clear/>
Line 52:         <add name="ActiveDirectoryProvider"
Line 53:           type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
Line 54:           connectionStringName="--Redacted--"
Line 55:           connectionUsername="--Redacted--"
```

I'm aware that the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` requires Full Trust, however, I would expect that that issue would both not be present in WAWS (as WAWS apps run under full trust by default), and that any issue with FT would produce an "Assembly not found" or "Assembly binding failed" exception, not a configuration exception.

Does anyone have any idea why the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` is not functioning correctly?

Thanks,
Ed

**EDIT**

Interestingly, I've set up a similar test website on a standard Azure Cloud Services instance and the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` works just fine.